# Ubuntu 14.04/14.10 multitouch screen support

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, laptop, multi-touch, touchscreen

I have a Dell E7240 laptop with a multitouch screen. It works perfectly in Windows 8 with multitouch gestures.

However Ubuntu 14.04/14.10 seem to ignore multitouch gestures coming from the screen and they are interpreted as mouse moves and clicks. However touchpad multitouch (double finger scrolling etc) works fine.

AFAIK Ubuntu 14 is supposed to support multitouch gestures coming from multitouch screens.

What can be done to diagnose screen multitouch ability and to enable multitouch screen gestures?